# How to bend text to create a typography portrait in illustrator?

Tags: typography, text, illustrator-effects, text-wrap, portrait

Trying to create a self portrait, I've already tried Envelope Distort---> Make with Mesh as I saw in the article link below, but the text gets distorted when I just want it to bend alone. Can you tell me in a few steps please, I need the help!  http://www.macprovideo.com/hub/photoshop/design-a-cool-typography-portrait-in-adobe-illustrator

Comment: Hi Miss Kee, you will have to be more specific on what you mean by "bend alone". How are you trying to change the text besides distorting it?

Comment: I want the angles of the text to change so that it all flows eg. as if it goes up a mountain and then down a valley, but it must all look like the same typeface, not stretched out or compacted.

Comment: The description is still a little ambiguous by angle, do you mean going up and dawn like it would be on the outside of a triangle? I would try to find an example or draw one that shows what you're trying to do. I would also look at the text effects I put into my answer. You may also want to look into the "Type on Path Tool".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what part are you having trouble with in the tutorial? Well the tool does as it describes, If you use the Envelope Distort tool then well it will distort the text based on how you move the anchor points.

Another way to shape your text is to use `Effect -> Warp -> (Choose your effect)`. Maybe Arc will work if you want to bend the text.

Comment: I'm getting it :) Thanks... Using envelope distort -> reset with warp Thanks again!